# Typescript: Generic enum types as index for another type

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, indexing, enums

I'm trying to create an indexed type whose index are the values of an `enum` BUT the `enum` comes from a generic argument.

```
export type EnumMap<TEnum extends string | undefined = undefined> = {
  [key: TEnum]: ValueClass;
}
export type EnumMap<TEnum extends string | undefined = undefined> = {
  [key: keyof TEnum]: ValueClass;
}
```

Both of those implementations shows the error:

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

When I implement it as a mapped object as suggested:

```
export type EnumMap<TEnum extends string | undefined = undefined> = {
  [TEnumKey in keyof TEnum]: ValueClass;
}
```

It doesn't show any errors at the definition but it only accepts `TEnum` instances as the value. It shows this error when I try to instantiate an `EnumMap`.

> Type '{ "test": ValueClass; }' is not assignable to type 'TestEnum'.

I'm using this `enum` as a test:

```
export enum TestEnum {
  test = 'test'
}
```

Is there any way to use a generic `enum` as a type's index?

PS.: I understand I can implement it using string as the key, but I want to tie the indexes to the enum values;

```
export type EnumMap = {
  [key: string]: ValueClass;
}
const map: EnumMap = { [TestEnum.test]: {...} }; // works fine
```

Comment: [Enums themselves are treated as "unions" when using them in a mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAMsAu9gCcDOUDeUCCUC8UARNoQDRQBC+RFZUAwtYfYVAL4BQH8AngA7AoAWQCGfAPIA3FAB4AolGAAPJCAAm6AArIA9gOS8A0sB4A+ahg5RrUANqGoASxBQ5AXQBcUVPGTOA5gDcHGzB3PyConwCatRRUrJwiCiopsEA9Ok2AHoA-EA). After all, they *are* **enumerations**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
enum Enum {
  "ABC" = "abc",
  "CDE" = "cde"
}

export type EnumMap<TEnum extends string = Enum> = {
  [key in TEnum]?: string;
}

const map: EnumMap = { [Enum.ABC]: "123" };
```

Since `TEnum` is a string union, you can use it as `[key in TEnum]` inside the index signature.

I am not sure why you used `string | undefined` for `TEnum`...